# In a JS for loop over elements, how do you act on those elements in the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original code:

```
item_boxes = $(".item-box")
$.each(item_boxes, function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id")
  $(this).find(".price").text(price_list[id])
})
```

JS code:

```
item_boxes = $(".item-box")
for(var i=0; i<item_boxes.length; i++) {
  var id = item_boxes[i].getAttribute("data-id")
  item_boxes[i].find... .text
  // above line doesn't work, because it's jQuery
  // item_boxes[i].querySelector(".price"), finds the child element, but then I can't figure out how to add the price info
  // item_boxes[i].querySelector(".price").innerHTML(price_list[id]) throws a nomethod error on innerHTML
}
```

ooops sorry tanks for the responses, but I guess the quesiton wasn't clear, I'm moving TO the latter code (JS). I'd like the latter code to duplicate the same functionailty as former, but currently it does not. `item_boxes[i].find` throws a no method error on `.find`, so then I did `querySelector`, which finds the object, but there's no `.text` method to change the text.

Basically what the code is doing is looking at all the `item_boxes`, and on each of them, changing the text of the child `price` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [eq(id)](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to fetch a jQuery object.
Proceed with `data()` as well.

```
var item_boxes = $(".item-box"),
    i = 0,
    el, id;

for(; i < item_boxes.length; i++) {
    el = item_boxes.eq(i);
    id = el.data("id");
    el.find(".price").text(price_list[id]);
}
```

Notice with the for loop, all variables are extracted to it's function scope, which is more imaginary in this example. Use `$.each(items, function(i, item){/*vars*/})` if you want to keep variables together.

---

Without jQuery:

```
var item_boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".item-box"),
    i = 0,
    el, id;

for(; i < item_boxes.length; i++) {
    el = item_boxes[i];
    id = el.dataset.id;
    //el.querySelectorAll
    el.querySelector(".price").innerHTML = price_list[id];
}
```

Comment: `el.querySelectorAll()` returns a list that doesn't have an `.innerHTML` property (and note that it is a property, not a method). It should be `el.querySelector(".price").innerHTML = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 Map method

It'd be something like

```
item_boxes.map( (item_box,index) =>  {
    var id = item_box.getAttribute("data-id")
    item_box.find... .text //if you actually need to do something with the index
})
```

Comment: If you're using `.map()` then the `item_box` parameter would be a reference to the individual item so you don't need the `[index]` part.

Answer (score 0):

Following [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.each/) sample :

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` takes two arguments. The first one is what it calls the index, the second one is what it calls the element.

As for "acting" on the data, it depends on whether you're talking about manipulating what you're iterating over or whether you're just manipulating the values that the function is returning.

To change what you're iterating over, use the index to select each respective item in what you're iterating over:

```
var list = [27, 43, 19];

$.each(list, function(i, element) {
    list[i] += 7
});
```

To change the values being returned, just do whatever. They're variables.

```
var list = [27, 43, 19];

$.each(list, function(i, element) {
    i += 3
    element += 91
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do much better without jQuery by using modern features, and a transpiler if needed.

```
for (const box of document.querySelectorAll(".item-box")) {
  box.querySelector(".price").textContent = price_list[box.dataset.id];
}
```

The longest part is the function names, so you can shorten them.

```
function query(root, sel) {
  return root.querySelector(sel);
}
function queryAll(root, sel) {
  return root.querySelectorAll(sel)
}
```

So now it looks like this:

```
for (const box of queryAll(document, ".item-box")) {
  query(box, ".price").textContent = price_list[box.dataset.id];
}
```

Make the function names as short as you like.